# Hbase on hadoop not connecting on distrubuted mode

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata, ubuntu-14.04, distributed

Hi I AM TRYING TO SETUP HBASE(hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2) ON HADOOP(hadoop-2.7.0)
Hadoop is running on localhost:560070 its running fine .

my  hbase-site.xml  as show below

```
<configuration>
    <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
  </property>

<!--  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>-->

  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
```

WHen I start ./start-hbase.sh I am getting this error in log file .

```
 2015-05-22 11:17:30,468 INFO  [master:bredgelinux-desktop:60000] Configuration.deprecation: fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
    2015-05-22 11:17:31,021 WARN  [Thread-13] hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
    org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /hbase/.tmp/hbase.version could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1549)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:641)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:330)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1078)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:514)
    2015-05-22 11:17:31,023 DEBUG [master:bredgelinux-desktop:60000] util.FSUtils: Unable to create version file at hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase, retrying
    org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /hbase/.tmp/hbase.version could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1549)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:641)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:330)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1078)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:514)
    2015-05-22 11:17:41,116 WARN  [Thread-16] hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
    org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /hbase/.tmp/hbase.version could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1549)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:641)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
```

- TIA

I am using Openjdk Here is JPS command similar result 
bredge-linux@bredgelinux-desktop:~$ sudo  netstat -plten | grep java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8042            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          29563       3356/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50090           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          27575       3063/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46766           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          29555       3356/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50070           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          25124       2723/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8088            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          29579       3224/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:13562           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          29562       3356/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8030            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          31542       3224/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8031            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          29571       3224/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8032            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          31546       3224/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8033            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          29581       3224/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8040            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          31536       3356/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          28260       2723/java

Datanode log file

```
2015-05-22 14:21:33,980 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 starting to offer service
2015-05-22 14:21:33,985 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2015-05-22 14:21:33,985 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 50020: starting
2015-05-22 14:21:35,073 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-05-22 14:21:36,073 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-05-22 14:21:36,391 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: DataNode version: -56 and NameNode layout version: -60
2015-05-22 14:21:36,443 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Lock on /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 4902@bredgelinux-desktop
2015-05-22 14:21:36,457 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Exiting. 
java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode: namenode clusterID = CID-654b4574-5929-4de9-ac12-f47de7f9fd75; datanode clusterID = CID-f70f0a9a-da72-4c70-b453-35227ceca6ce
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.doTransition(DataStorage.java:646)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.addStorageLocations(DataStorage.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:1311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:828)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-05-22 14:21:36,459 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Ending block pool service for: Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000
2015-05-22 14:21:36,461 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Removed Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned)
2015-05-22 14:21:38,461 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exiting Datanode
2015-05-22 14:21:38,474 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
2015-05-22 14:21:38,476 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at bredgelinux-desktop/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now Hbase is running on hadoop . Directories 'datanode' and 'namenode' were not accessible. May be because of this Hadoop was not able to access  these directories . I did chmod 777 on these directories and namenode format and restarted system .Now after this My habse is running on port 61000 . Thanks every one for your reply .

Answer (score 1):

> java.net.ConnectException: Call From bredgelinux-desktop/**127.0.1.1** to localhost:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

This error occurs if you have loopback IP address. Follow these steps to rectify this error:

**STEP 1:** Remove the line with `127.0.1.1` from /`etc/hosts`.

**STEP 2:** Restart your hadoop and hbase processess.

Comment: Try to change `localhost` to `hbase-master-hostname` or `hbase-master-ip` in `hbase-site.xml` for all nodes. Restart all hadoop and hbase processes. Try to avoid using localhost in configs.

Comment: I tried by replacing localhost by IP but  doesnt seems that's a  issue .

Comment: Post the new log. Also, post the result for `jps` for all nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I guess (because I've seen a similar error in data node logs before) that you've deleted your datanode data directory and restarted it.

Try to bring the HDFS down (datanodes and namenode), delete namenode and datanode data directories, start the cluster up and format namenode.

Comment: Thanks .I did it and Now its running fine